# Error installing CocoaPods in 10.11.4 (15E65) EL Capitan

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoapods

I am trying to install the CocoaPods, but it shows me the following error.

Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0) in any repository

i have tried it all but still above log i got from the console . if any one have any solution on this please let me know, thanks

The version for the Xcode and OSX is,

Xcode  - 7.3 ,
OSX - 10.11.4 (15E65) EL Capitan

Comment: Did you try to install with `sudo gem install cocoapods`?

Comment: run `traceroute rubygems.org` check result ( to make sure you are not blocked to the site )

Comment: @ridvankucuk yes, But not helping me out.

Comment: @Rahul its gives unknown host rubygems.org

Comment: @RajKumar So you are blocked to rubygems.org that is the issue for you. Just use some proxies . i think this will help you [http-proxies-and-ruby](http://www.linux-support.com/cms/http-proxies-and-ruby/)

Comment: Can you check `gem sources`

Comment: @Rahul This link give a black blank Page...

Comment: @Rahul when i checked the gem sources it give *** CURRENT SOURCES ***

Comment: @RajKumar please run `gem sources --add http://rubygems.org/`

Comment: @Rahul Do you want to add this insecure source? [yn]  y
Error fetching http://rubygems.org/:
 no such name (http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Comment: @Rahul I am getting like this

Comment: oh.... can you try https://rubygems.org/

Comment: @RahulCould not find a valid gem 'rubygems-update' (>= 0) in any repository

Comment: Please use some proxy... 'sudo gem install --http-proxy http://user:password@www-proxy.example.com:80 cocoapods'

Comment: @Rahul Even this also not working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 1**:

@Raj: Try these steps, it helped me fix the same issue, hope it helps you too:

$ mkdir -p $HOME/Software/ruby

$ export GEM_HOME=$HOME/Software/ruby

$ gem install cocoapods

[...]
1 gem installed

$ export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Software/ruby/bin

$ pod --version

Source [Github](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3692)

Comment: Sorry Its Not working.. I am getting the error like apples-iMac:~ apple$ sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoa pods
Password:
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoa' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'pods' (>= 0) in any repository